# JODD Message parsing failed; <--- java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: imap, jodd

I'm using Jodd version 3.9 and I would like to read an outlook account (Microsoft Exchange).
]

```
    int port = 993;
    ImapSslServer imapServer = new ImapSslServer("mail.myhost.it", port, "authuser", "authpass");
    imapServer.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "15000");

    ReceiveMailSession session = imapServer.createSession();
    session.open();
    _log.info("total number of inbox emails : " + session.getMessageCount());
    ReceivedEmail[] emails = session.receiveEmailAndMarkSeen(EmailFilter.filter().flag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, false));
```

but i get this error at the line : `session.receiveEmailAndMarkSeen(...)`

```
jodd.mail.MailException: Message parsing failed; <--- 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this is a debug:

```
A8 FETCH 4 (BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 4 FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE (("text" "plain" ("charset" "us-ascii") NIL NIL "7bit" 1401 35 NIL NIL NIL NIL) "mixed" ("boundary" "----=_Part_1029639_1159929762.1507643405808") NIL NIL))

[ERROR] 11 ott 04:57:31.467 PM [com.afterbit.jobs.EmailJob] (mGxTfT0) EXCEPTION session.receiveEmailAndMarkSeen : jodd.mail.MailException: Message parsing failed; <--- java.lang.NullPointerException

A9 CLOSE
A8 OK FETCH completed.
A9 OK CLOSE completed.
```

I cannot understand why...

Comment: You forgot to add a question and include a stack trace...

Comment: Can you please give me a line number for `java.lang.NullPointerException` so I can at least write something better in the exception? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] I hope this help... and save time (i have spend many days..)
there is a conflict between javamail and apache CXF.
apache cxf has a inner file geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar .. so if you add into your project also mail.jar (javamail) and use IMAP protocol, it can generate error like above!

Comment: Thank you, I will add this to the FAQ section